# Css animations - animation is slow and jiggles

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I wanted to ask, what is wrong with this CSS code? It is used to animate background image - zoom effect.

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .anim-on {
    background-size: 110% 110%;
    background-position: center center;
    animation: shrink 12s infinite alternate;
  }
  .anim-out {
    background-size: 120% 120%;
    background-position: center center;
    animation: small 6s infinite alternate;
  }
  @keyframes shrink {
    0% {
      background-size: 110% 110%;
    }
    100% {
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
  }
  @keyframes small {
    0% {
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    100% {
      background-size: 110% 110%;
    }
  }
}
```

This code generates nice effect, but i saw, that on slower machines, affect is bad.

What is wrong? Or maybe someone has better idea, how create this effect, in better technique?

Comment: Changing `background-size` will cause a repaint to happen and so it will impact performance.

Comment: It's a nice question, but doesn't it rather belong to Code Review instead of SO?

Comment: @FaustoNA "what is wrong with the code" **is clearly off topic** for Code Review.

Comment: @Heslacher In this case there's something wrong with the performance, I haven't noticed any bugs.

Comment: Code Review is made for Q&A related to working code that needs improvement, just like this one. I'm not saying it's bad that the OP posted it here, just trying to figure things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background size is a visual property and so any change to its value would cause repainting to occur. Painting is a very expensive operation and is bound to have an impact on the performance in low end machines. One way to overcome this would be to use CSS `transform` (scale to be precise) instead of `background-size` change to produce the animation.

**Snippet which will cause performance impact:**

The below snippet uses the same animation as in the question. When you run this snippet and inspect it using Chrome Dev tools (by enabling "Show Paint Rects" option), you'd see that both images have a paint rect associated with them (green or red colored box) and that as the animation is happening the box keeps blinking (or stays as-is). This indicates that a repaint is happening often and thus it impacts performance.

```css
.anim-on,
.anim-out {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1);
}
.anim-on {
  background-size: 110% 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  animation: shrink 12s infinite alternate;
}
.anim-out {
  background-size: 120% 120%;
  background-position: center center;
  animation: small 6s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    background-size: 110% 110%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes small {
  0% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 110% 110%;
  }
}
/* Just for demo */

div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class='anim-on'></div>
<div class='anim-out'></div>
```

---

**Snippet which will cause lesser performance impact:**

In the below snippet, I have added the `background-image` to a pseudo-element and then used `scale` transform on it to produce the zoom-in/out effect. The parent's `overflow: hidden` setting prevents the animation from affecting its size. If you inspect this with Chrome Dev tools you'd see that the green or red colored box appears only once when the page is loaded and goes away. This indicates that there is no further repaint is happening during the animation itself and hence it is better from a performance point of view. You'd also notice that this animation is more smoother than the earlier one.

```css
.anim-on,
.anim-out {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.anim-on:after,
.anim-out:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1);
}
.anim-on:after {
  animation: shrink 12s infinite alternate;
}
.anim-out:after {
  animation: small 6s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes small {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
/* Just for demo */

div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class='anim-on'></div>
<div class='anim-out'></div>
```

You can find more information about the various CSS properties and how a change to their value will impact the rendering process in the [CSS Triggers website](http://csstriggers.com/).

You can find more information about the rendering process and how using `transform` (as opposed to few other properties) results in a performance improvement in the below articles/sites:

- [HTML5 Rocks - Accelerated Rendering in Chrome](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/)
- [GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome).
- [Google Developers - Rendering Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. But i have question: i have to change all background images in css file, as i need to add .anim-on:after,
.anim-out:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1);
}
? If yes, situation is getting complicated, as this anim-in and anim-out declarations will not be universal ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see any other better choices because `background-size` animation is very expensive. I'll think more and update the answer if I find any better method. I'd suggest you to leave the question open for the day in hope that we may get better suggestions.

Comment: Just to note Harry - i will search of something more reusable - for example just to add to div with background image some class to auto animate - but i just wanted to say Thank You anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited Henry code, now css is reusable, so user can add background image to element via CMS, and css code will do the rest:

```
.anim {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 **background-size: 0px!important;**

}
.anim:after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-size: cover !important;
 **background: inherit;**
 z-index: -1;
}
.anim:after {
animation: shrink 12s infinite alternate;
 }
@keyframes shrink {
0% {
transform: scale(1.1);
}
 100% {
transform: scale(1);
}
}
@keyframes small {
0% {
transform: scale(1);
}
100% {
transform: scale(1.1);
}
}

<section class="anim" style="background: url('images/1.png');"></section>
```

Thanks * :)