# How to make a background image zoom in and out slowly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I would like to bring some more interactive elements into my webpage.

What i've seen before on some website's, is that the background image zoom's in slowly and back out. So that it looks more like a living thing.

I've been searching on the internets and here. But i dont know how this technique is done exactly and i dont know the name for this kind of effect.

I also think this should be fairly easy to achiev this with some CSS3 and HTML5.

The questions are:

- Is there a name for this effect and what is it called?
- Can it be done with pure CSS?
- Is there a sample online availble for the basics?

Here is the html i had in mind:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test page</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LXR5gFx.png");
                background-size: 100% auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

The goal is to let the background image zooming in slowly and back out. Like it is breathing.

Comment: It can be easily done using Css.Use the dev tools in your browser. Hint: Learn about :hover in css.

Comment: I'm  kinda familiar with the :hover . But the background should always keep moving. Even when there is no mouse activity is involved

Comment: You can achieve the animation with `background-size` property as shown in the answer here but it is not advisable because background size is a visual property and so any change will cause repaint which will affect performance. A better way would be to use `transform` like in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311417/css-animations-animation-is-slow-and-jiggles/34312019#34312019 (second snippet). I think the animation in that answer is also quite close to what you want.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 16):

There is mainly 2 different ways, using either `animation` or `transition`.

`animation` is normally better when one want something running all the time, and `transition` is more efficient for e.g. *hover* effects.

Here is a start using `animation`.

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

@keyframes breath {
  0%   { background-size: 100% auto; }
  50% { background-size: 140% auto; }
  100% { background-size: 100% auto; }
}

#bkg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: breath 4s linear infinite;
  background: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LXR5gFx.png") center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="bkg"></div>
```

---

And here is another using `transition` and `:hover`.

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

#bkg {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bkg::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LXR5gFx.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform .5s linear;
}

#bkg:hover::before{
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="bkg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That saved alot of time! And it works like a charm!
So the css i was looking for is called. Animation : breath: 
:)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called keyframes.

This is the code in the following example.

```
@keyframes zoom {
0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
50% { transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
100% {
    transform:scale(1,1); 
}
}
```

Css transform has properties which can br run "frame by frame", in the above, we want the picture to be zoomed by the factor 1.2 on the x and y axis by the time 50% of the animation have passed.
We start at no zoom, zoom it by 20% and then we go back tot he original state.

And here is how we add this to the class:

```
animation: zoom 30s infinite;
```

just add that to your class and it will run. There are more parameters, but this gets complicated for someone who is unfamiliar with, thus, an easy example.

Here the link to the codepen in action

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/QyqRgw

Comment: I am not sure whether or not it's ok to post links to tutorials, I think just looking it up on wc3 or mdn is not very beginner friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a separate element with `transform()`, for three reasons:

- It will use the GPU to render the element
- It will be more performant in terms of FPS [more on that](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)
- Animating the `body` background will cause the entire page to repaint on every frame

Also, animating the `background-position` will create a juggle effect, as the browser will try to round the position to the nearest pixel.

With a `transform: scale()` on the other hand, the browser will position the element with subpixel rendering, resulting in a way smoother movement.

```css
@keyframes breath {
  from { 
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.05)
  }
}

div{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: breath 2s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
  background: url("https://www.placecage.com/800/600");
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```